# About circular dependency & #includes in C++

Tags: c++, include, circular-dependency

I've read several questions here about circular dependencies when using `#include` in the header files of classes , so for example:
// sorry edited the example to be clear

File Car.h

```
#include "Wheel.h"
#include <vector>

class Car
{
    std::vector<Wheel> wheels;
};
```

File Wheel.h

```
#include "Car.h"
class Wheel
{
    Car* car;
};
```

A compile error happens due to the circular dependency occurring between the 2 classes.  My question is why if I just used `#include "Wheel.h"` in the .cpp of class Car or `#include "Car.h"` in the .cpp of class Wheel, the problem is solved. Isn't it still a circular dependency?

Comment: please show a real example, in what you show you neither need to include B.h in A.h nor A.h in B.h. There is no circular dependency between `A` and `B`

Comment: in other words, mutual inclusion is a symptom of circular dependency, but not the cause

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolve build errors due to circular dependency amongst classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes)

Comment: sorry I edited the example to a working one , can you view it again ?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> //A.h
> #include "B.h"
> class A
> {}
>
> //////////////
>
> //B.h
> #include "A.h"
> class B
> {}
> ```

There is no circular dependency in the shown code. Neither class depends on the other. (The code won't compile however, due to syntax errors).

Circular include simply means that one header is not before the other despite having been included at the top. This is simply because both cannot be before the other at the same time. If the class defined in the header that was included first depends on the one that was included second, then there would be an error.

---

Update for the new example:

In this case, `Car` depends on the definition of `Wheel` and `Wheel` depends on the declaration of `Car`. Note that `Wheel` does not depend on the definition of `Car`. It does not need to know what kind of class `Car` is, only that it is a class.

> My question is why if I just used #include "Wheel.h" in the .cpp of class Car or #include "Car.h" in the .cpp of class Wheel, the problem is solved.

This is not correct, this does not solve the problem. It might make the problem disappear, but the program will remain buggy.

The correct solution is to include the definition of `Wheel` before `Car` is defined, and declare `Car` before `Wheel` is defined. Like this:

```
class Car;

class Wheel
{
    Car* car;
};

class Car
{
    std::vector<Wheel> wheels;
};
```

Comment: sorry I edited my question to a working example , can you view it again ?